# Dagger best practice

Tags: android, dagger

I'm trying to figure out dagger and having a hard time to grasp the concept of the object graphs. 
I'm not new to the dependency injection paradigm, I used angular.js in JavaScript and prism in .Net. So I do understand the idea behind it.

1. What I can't seem to understand is whether the object graph should be actually a single graph, meaning one in all the app and all the dependencies should be injected from it or should I create one for each module.
2. I want to create an instance of a class with injectables, so should I use an existing object graph or create a new one?
3. Where is best practice to create multiple mudules ? Should I create object graph per module as a singleton? Create one object graph for all the app that every class should use? Or should I create a new object graph each time I need a new instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think of Object Graphs or Components (if using dagger2) as a way to scope objects.  You mentioned you used .Net so I am assuming you are familiar with scoping.  Rather than creating a graph for each module I would recommend creating an object graph for each scope.  A common pattern is to have an Application scope and then "plus" the activity graph/component onto the Application scope.  You can have 1 to many modules per component.  Modules are more of a way to split dependencies into different files (even thought they may still be in same component).  CodePath has a pretty good intro on Dagger including going into scopes as well as multiple modules per component.  Best of Luck! https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2